# How to debug using WAMP?

Tags: php, debugging, windows-xp, wamp

I just installed WAMP on Windows XP. I have a simple PHP file that is crashing. I ran it from command line using `php test.php`.

What is the best way to debug php files? How do I display debugging info?

I looked at php.ini and it includes `display_errors = On`. Does this do anything?

I tried turning on XDebug from the PHP WAMP menu. This doesn't seem to do anything, besides restarting the server. Do I need to use this? How?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have an error log file...possibly C:\wamp...\log...?

Comment: You typically run a debugging session (using XDebug for example) from an IDE. Netbeans can use XDebug nicely, give it a try.

Comment: Which PHP IDE is free, simple to use, and easy to learn?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look at the log at `c:/wamp/logs/php_error.log`. If you are not sure whether your PHP log is being redirected here, check your `php.ini` file and search for a line like this:

`;error_log = "c:/wamp/logs/php_error.log"`

You may want to remove the comment on this line.

Answer (score 2):

As much as i know about PHP and WAMP.I don't think there is any special debugging option available in this.for the debugging you need to print the answer using echo and exit function wherever in your code you feel the error may posible. The other option is, you need to use software which provide debugging facility such as eclipse with php.

Answer (score 1):

I am using WAMPSERVER 2.4 on Windows 8 pro. I was using WAMP on localhost.

It appears that in my version of WAMP, the php.ini file had appeared as:

```
;error_log = "Z:/wamp/logs/php_error.log"
```

When in actuality,for me get the function `error_log()` to work properly, I wanted it to appear as :

```
error_log = "Z:/wamp/logs/php_error.log"
```